# I want to access filter data while searching in Material Table React - how to access or is there any method to access or triggered while searching

Tags: reactjs, material-table

[image]
i am trying to update the data according to search filter in material table, i didn't find any method or param by which  i access the data updated on search filter, i can call an api and provide search filter but it may slow down the query so i want to do it on frontend side.

i have tried the method above mentioned handleSearchChange which only give the search query nothing else, if i can get access the data of updated after searching in search field then i can do what i want

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer for the above query I have posted, the simple way to use the useRef in material table, by which you can access the current data of your table displaying.

```
tableRef={tableRef}
```

to access the data you can use

```
tableRef?.current?.state.data
```